# Execute task.dependsOn only on a Condition in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have two tasks `Task-A` and `Task-B`

This is my **Task-A**

```
task Task-A () {
  doLast {
    def fileName = _.property('fileName')
    if (fileName !=null) {
            println 'success'
   }
  }
}
```

My **Task-B** is dependent on Task-A and I should make it dependent only on the Condition that `_.property('fileName')` should exist and should not be null

So I wrote my Task-B this way

```
task Task-B () {
      doFirst {
        def fileName = _.property('fileName')
        if (fileName !=null) {
            dependsOn 'Task-A'
        }
       }
 }
```

It throws an Error

`Cannot call Task.dependsOn(Object...) on task ':Task-B' after task has started execution.`

How to execute `dependsOn` on a condition ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set `dependsOn` directives during the configuration phase

try :

```
task Task-B () {
    def fileName = _.property('fileName')
    if (fileName !=null) {
        dependsOn 'Task-A'
    }
}
```

Comment: Lovely ... It worked like a Charm . Thank you very much !!